# Understanding NegativelyOrientedPoints and PositivelyOrientedPoints

Tags: functions, regions, polygons

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[2];
p1 = RandomPolygon[{"Convex", 5}];
polypts = PolygonCoordinates@p1;
chmpts = (ConvexHullMesh[p1] // MeshPrimitives[#, 0] &) /. 
   Point :> Sequence;

g1 = MapThread[Text[#1, #2] &, {Range@Length@polypts, polypts}] // 
   Graphics;
g2 = MapThread[Text[#1, #2] &, {Range@Length@chmpts, chmpts}] // 
   Graphics;
Grid[{{Framed@g1, Spacer[10], Framed@g2}}]
```

[image]

The following inputs are returned unevaluated:

```
Through[{NegativelyOrientedPoints, PositivelyOrientedPoints}[polypts]]
Through[{NegativelyOrientedPoints, PositivelyOrientedPoints}[chmpts]]
```

**Question**

Aren't the `chmpts` (picture to the right above) oriented CCW i.e., positively oriented?

Thanks for your help.

---

*Observation* (Few moments later)

[image]

[image]

where `d` is the dimension.

Comment: If I correctly understand the documentation, in two dimensions `NegativelyOrientedPoints/PositivelyOrientedPoints`  can be applied only to three points. For example, `PositivelyOrientedPoints[chmpts[[1 ;; 3]]]` produces `True`.

Comment: This is not [as advertised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XjEV.png).

Comment: Read Details: "In d dimensions, d+1 points p1,p2,…,pd+1 are negatively oriented if the determinant of the matrix {p2-p1,…,pd+1-p1} is negative". Of course, the documentation leaves much to be desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand the documentation, in two dimensions `NegativelyOrientedPoints/PositivelyOrientedPoints` can be applied only to three points. For example, `PositivelyOrientedPoints[chmpts[[1 ;; 3]]]` produces `True`. You can consequently consider `PositivelyOrientedPoints[chmpts[[2 ;; 4]]]` and so on.

Comment: Thanks. `Partition[chmpts, 3, 1, 1] // Map[PositivelyOrientedPoints]` returns `{True, True, True, True, True}` whereas `Partition[polypts, 3, 1, 1] // Map[PositivelyOrientedPoints]` does not.

Comment: @Syed: In fact,  these are `PositveOrientedVectors/NegativeOrientedVectors`.

Comment: Is `PositiveOrientedVectors` a command in newer versions? I am running v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: @Syed: No, there is not such a command in Mathematica at the present.